# Python try except: InvalidSyntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, fpdf, pyfpdf

I'm trying the [Designer GUI TOOL](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Templates/index.html) of pyFpdf but upon running the `designer.py` with `python designer.py` it gives an error:

```
  File "designer.py", line 154
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked the python file at line 154 and it's this code:

```
try:
    values[field] = eval(dlg.textctrls[field].GetValue())
except Exception, e:
    msg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, unicode(e),
           "Error in field %s" % field,
            wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION
            )
    msg.ShowModal()
    msg.Destroy()
    break
```

Is it the pyfpdf's problem?
I'm running `Python 3.8`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's pyfpdf's problem. This is Python2 syntax. There should be a newer version on the project site which is written for Python3. They also describe the problem [here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python3/index.html).